# Adobe Analytics Phonegap Plugin

Tags: cordova, adobe-analytics

Intending to implement Adobe Analytics along with Phonegap so as to define the custom events and track the events of the mobile app . Can anyone suggest me the best way as in plugins to execute this along with the proper documentation to carry out the same .

Comment: Could you be a little more precise on your question, do you just need to attach Adobe Analytics on your app and if so, is there some particular need for plugin? As Adobe Analytics (AFAIK) is plain JavaScript (as Google Analytics), there is no need for plugin necessarily.

Comment: Yeah , there is a need of plugin cause i need to define custom events which i need to keep a track of through adobe analytics ! or else can you share this plain javascript of this Adobe Analytics so that i can check if that serves my purpose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging more into this, the easiest way really seems to be using the plugin provided by Adobe itself. Though no plugin is necessarily needed as proved by [angulartics](https://github.com/luisfarzati/angulartics) which also supports Adobe Analytics with plain JavaScript.

The plugin however can found from [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/tree/master/sdks/Cordova) with the basic instructions on how to integrate. Basically it should be as easy as just installing the plugin with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services.git
```

then configuring the *ADBMobileConfig.json* to match your needs, and then you can use it like

```
<button style="height:200px; width:600px" onclick = "window.ADB.trackState('login page', {'user':'john','remember':'true'});">sampleHit</button>
```

after you have attached it to your create, pause and resume handlers appropriately.

The place I found the original link to the GitHub repository is [this](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/get-started/mobile/c-measuring-mobile-applications) page about *Measuring and Optimizing Mobile Applications*.

Comment: do you have any idea how to initalize the object ADB of the plugin ... i mean is the code  ADB = window.plugins.ADB;
 correct ? for initailizing object of the plugin. the detailed problem description is here ..    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821704/cant-read-property-abd-of-the-undefined-adobe-analytics-phonegap-plugin

thanks in advance @sanfor

Comment: @Learner: Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer, if it solved the problem for this question. I will take a look at the other question too.

Comment: For Cordova/PhoneGap apps, Adobe DTM or Launch are also options. See here for details... http://www.hickendesign.com/site/2017/05/rock-mobile-apps-cordova-adobe-dtm-launch/