# Can't read property 'ABD' of the undefined - Adobe Analytics Phonegap Plugin

Tags: cordova, adobe-analytics

Intending to Use the ADBPhoneGap Plugin to implement the Adobe Analytics in my mobile App.
Following is the code , i am trying along with the basic configurations asked to do in the [Link](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/android/phonegap.html).
The error i am getting is Can't read the Property 'ADB' of the Undefined. How to fix the issue. Also not able to figure out what and where to implement the 'Lifecycle Metrics Auto Tracking' mentioned in the above link. Can anyone help with the basic script for trackState or trackAction method , with reference to the following example .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" /> -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ADB_Helper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var ADB;
    function initialize() {
    alert('In initalize');
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            //alert('Device Ready');
        alert('Exit initalize');
        }
        function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('in On Device Ready method');
            ADB = window.plugins.ADB;
                        alert('Exit On Device Ready method'+ADB);
            // Note: A request for permission is REQUIRED by google. You probably want to do this just once, though, and remember the answer for subsequent runs.
            navigator.notification.confirm('GA_PLUGIN would like your permission to collect usage data. No personal or user identifiable data will be collected.', permissionCallback, 'Attention', 'Allow,Deny');
        }

    function TrackButtonClicked()
    {
    alert('Track Button Entry');
//  ADB.trackState("login page", {"user":"john","remember":"true"});
    alert('Track Button Exit');
    }
    </script>
   </head>
  <body onload="initialize();"  id="stage" class="theme"> <!-- onunload="goingAway();" -->

<h1>Test Adobe Analytics Plugin</h1>
<div class="space"></div>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="TrackButtonClicked();">Track Event</a>
    <!--<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="VariableButtonClicked();">Track Event with Variable</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="PageButtonClicked();">Track Page</a>-->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in [ADBHelper.js](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/blob/master/sdks/Cordova/ADBMobile/Shared/ADBHelper.js) variable called *ADB* is already declared, it seems that you are overwriting it two times in your code. First you [shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it with the

```
var ADB
```

on your global scope, which practically means overwriting it. Then you do

```
ADB = window.plugins.ADB;
```

which again sets it as *window.plugins.ADB* which seems to be *undefined*.

So remove this two lines, after that, if the plugin is correctly installed, the *ADB* should already be object containing the methods for Adobe Analytics.

Comment: Going on further , with that i try to execute the TrackLocation by the code ADB.trackLocation('40.431596', '-111.893713'); which gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError : Object #<Object> has no method 'exec' , " ... Do you have any idea for the same ? @sanfor

Comment: Since _cordova.exec_ is _undefined_, you are trying to call the ADB before _deviceReady_ event, so wait for it.

Comment: so what could be the fix for this , can you help me out @sanfor

Comment: @Learner: `document.addEventListener("deviceReady", function(){//Here call the ADB}, false)`

Comment: Still getting the same error, after calling the ADB in the deviceready method .. Uncaught referenceError : corodova is not defined window.addEventListener('load',function(){
   alert('HI');
    ADB.trackLocation('40.431596', '-111.893713');
});

Comment: Thankyou . there was a issue with cordova built as well !